# Spark import of Parquet files converts strings to bytearray

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

I have an uncompressed Parquet file which has "crawler log" sort of data.

I import it into Spark via PySpark as

`sq = SQLContext(sc)
 p = sq.read.parquet('/path/to/stored_as_parquet/table/in/hive')
 p.take(1).show()`

This shows strings in the source data converted to

`Row(host=bytearray(b'somehostname'), (checksum=bytearray(b'stuff'))...)`

When I do p.dtypes I see

`((host binary), (checksum binary) ....).`

What can I do to avoid this conversion or alternately how do I convert back to what I need

i.e. when I do p.dtypes I want to see

`((host string), (checksum string) ....)`

Thanks.

Comment: Can Parquet be uncompressed?  How is the Parquet file being created?  Looks like it is being written as a bytearray ....

Comment: the parquet file itself has everything declared as string and in hive it presents as strings - it is created as a result of writing out from spark as the result of an ETL job.  As a hive table it looks fine. When I pull subset tables of it into Spark I get this behavior.

Comment: I did not explicitly ask for it to be compressed on creation and INFO messages say the file is UNCOMPRESSED.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. Adding

```
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.parquet.binaryAsString","true")
```

right after creating my SqlContext, solved it for me.

Answer (score 5):

For spark 2.0 or later

set runtime options

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.binaryAsString","true")
```

Answer (score 1):

For people using `SparkSession` it is:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.config('spark.sql.parquet.binaryAsString', 'true').getOrCreate().newSession()
```